# Upgrade plan for TFS 2005 to TFS 2010?

Tags: team-foundation-server

The current TFS 2005 server runs on WS 2003 SP1 32-bit and SQL 2005.  Clients are all VS 2008 but may be VS 2010 by the time we do this.  The new machine will be WS 2008 R2 64-bit and SQL 2008 SP1.  The ideal plan would allow users to continue working on the 2005 server until all migration issues are ironed out and then switch them to the new server and TFS 2010.  A few hours of down time can be tolerated if needed though.

We don't use Sharepoint for anything outside of TFS' requirements so we don't care about any of the other data there.

Has anyone done this and have any suggestions?  What's the best way to get this going?  I fear we may need to have an interim step of TFS 2008 somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only recently moved a TFS 2008 installation to TFS 2010 Beta 2, but in a quick Google search it looks like an upgrade from 2005 is possible.  Check this link on bharry's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/21/upgrading-from-tfs-2005-2008-to-tfs-2010.aspx